# Neovim scroll option not persisting from config

Tags: lua, editor, config, neovim

I'd like to permanently set the [scroll](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27scroll%27) option in my Neovim config to a set value, but the option doesn't persist when I set it in my init.lua file.

~/.config/nvim/init.lua:

```lua
vim.o.scroll = 20
```

The docs have this to say about the scroll property:

*"Will be set to half the number of lines in the window when the window size changes. This may happen when enabling the status-line or 'tabline' option after setting the 'scroll' option"*

I haven't changed the status-line or tabline options, and I've tried setting scroll at the bottom of my config file. I suspect the size of the window is being changed at some point which is resetting the scroll property.

Is there a workaround for this? Or something I'm missing?

[My config file](https://gist.github.com/Bdeering1/98965b0b93150e0e38528b3ebf633d79) for reference (based on the [kickstart](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim) config):